# Using Powershell to migrate folder rights to another server

Tags: windows-server-2003, powershell

I am interested in finding Powershell scripts that can be used\tweaked to migrate folder permissions across servers\environments.

Is this a feasible approach? I would like to automate our deployment process a little more.

Can someone point me to an example?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to copy the folders as well or just the permissions?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/482446/using-powershell-to-migrate-folder-rights-to-another-server).  Ask your question in one place, if you discover it is the wrong place flag it for migration.

Comment: Server Fault is for answering actual questions, not collating a list of things. If you have a specific question about a script, then feel free to ask again.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to use PowerShell or if you need to use PowerShell.

If you dont need to, just use Robocopy.

This script would copy files;

```
robocopy.exe "\\SOURCESRV\ShareName" "\\DESTSRV\ShareName" /E /SEC /R:1
```

The /R:1 switch is not essential, just stops the program from hanging if it cannot read a file.

Maybe enable a log to monitor in case this happens? /Log:C: